# How to guard against "Option" argument?

Tags: scala

Below I have some scala code that should log "hi" if the argument to example is `true`. However this logs `()` 3 times.

```scala
class Poplar {
  def hello (): String =
    "hi"

  def example (runHello: Option[Boolean]) {
    if (runHello.isDefined) hello
    None
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val p = new Poplar()
  println(p.example(Some(true)))
  println(p.example(Some(false)))
  println(p.example(None))
}
```

What is wrong about the above code that doesn't allow the code to log 'hi'?

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems, but the main one is that `if (runHello.isDefined) hello` is just ignored and then the function always returns `None` because that is the last expression of your code. Try with `else None` but then you have the problem that your function returns `Any` and that it is using deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```scala
def example(runHello: Option[Boolean]) {
  // code
}
```

is (deprecated) syntactic sugar for

```scala
def example(runHello: Option[Boolean]): Unit = {
  // code
}
```

Unless the `-Ywarn-value-discard` compiler option (which will reject code like this, which is why it's a very useful compiler option) is in effect, the code block can result in any value: since there's only one possible value for `Unit` (that value is `()`) the "conversion" is trivial (albeit literally one which discards the value).

Your `println` then prints the value (`()`) which it receives from calling `example`, thus the three printings of `()`.

I would suggest:

- changing the result type of `example` to `Option[String]`: it will return `Some("hi")` if the given option contains `true` and `None` otherwise
- In your `main`, printing the results using `foreach`:

```scala
p.example(Some(true)).foreach(println _)
p.example(Some(false)).foreach(println _)
p.example(None).foreach(println _)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the others in this post I arrived at:

```scala
class Poplar {
  def hello (): String =
    "hi"

  def example (runHello: Option[Boolean]): Option[String] = {
    val rh = runHello.getOrElse(false)
    if (rh) Some(hello)
    else None
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val p = new Poplar()
  println(p.example(Some(true)))
  println(p.example(Some(false)))
  println(p.example(None))
}
```

Which will only log "hi" for the first println.

Comment: If `hello` don't have side effects then you should remove the empty parameter list, if it has, then you must provide the empty parameter list on-call site. - Also, what you have there is equivalent to `runHello.collect { case true => hello() }`